# What is a word that means "someone who pretends to be your friend but is actually your enemy?"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

What do you call someone who pretends to be your friend but is actually your enemy?

A friend suggested *spy* for me, but that does not nearly describe the word I need for an English project. The character is very good at manipulating how people see him. He's a good liar. And pretends to be your friend but actually is your enemy.

Comment: You call him a friend.  You wont know who your real friends are until after you have been locked alone in a room together to starve to death.

Comment: phony, slimy, two-faced ...

Comment: I do so wish one could use the ancient *unfriend* here, which dates from the 13th century. But an unfriend is really nothing other than an enemy.  Sir Walter Scott wrote in 1814 “He is a very unquiet neighbour to his **un-friends.”**

Comment: And JRR Tolkien in the 20th century wrote both “And these folk are hewers of trees and hunters of beasts; therefore we are their **unfriends,** and if they will not depart we shall afflict them in 
all ways that we can.” in *The Silmarillion* and “For Fëanor beheld the hair of Galadriel with wonder and delight. He begged three times for a tress, but Galadriel would not give him even one hair. These two kinsfolk, the greatest of the Eldar of Valinor, were **unfriends** for ever.” in *Unfinished Tales*.

Comment: If your friend suggested *spy*, I don't think he's really your friend. I think he's a spy.

Comment: Is "manipulator" considered a word?

Comment: @JohnOdom Sure, why not? Everybody knows what it means. Admittedly, the term is somewhat new to English though, dating to only 1851 at least per the OED2, so that may be why you question it. The OED gives two primary senses for a *manipulator*; the first is for **a manipulative person** and the second is for a **waldo** — that is, for a tool to facilitate the remote manipulation of other objects, including radioactive ones as one specific subsense. The human version can be used disparagingly, and includes subsenses related to being manipulatory of various financial instruments.

Comment: I like 'turncoat' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turncoat), although that implies a one-time permanent betrayal rather than something more long lived.

Comment: I'll leave "imposter" here, because it hasn't been mentioned yet.

Comment: Per American teenager slang, 'frenemy' ;)

Comment: 'Frenemy' can mean an ambiguous relationship, and if you're looking for the King's English, that word is not there just yet. :)  I'm not sure there is a specific word for someone who pretends friendship but is, and always has been, truly an enemy in every sense.  'Traitor' or any variation on disloyalty tends to mean someone who actually was friendly, but then turns on you.

Comment: @wilee been there since 1950ish http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/frenemy, the king however ...

Comment: @Bobo: I think teenagers would refer to such a person as "bitch". I think the term is actually quite appropriate given the description of the person, but may not be considered appropriate for a term paper. I would certainly consider using the term for such a person in an informal essay or fictional narrative.

Comment: "Two-faced" is the first term that comes to mind, along with "double-dealing" and "backstabber".  Probably the term you'd use would depend to some degree on your background and status.  And, of course, there's a good chance that this person is a psychopath.

Comment: I think this is a badly worded question, because it is ambiguous whether you are looking for a word that _means_ "a person who pretends to be a friend but isn't", or whether you are looking for general invective that would be appropriate to apply to such a person.   Many of the voted answers below are the latter, which I don't think is really what you were looking for?

Answer (score 38):

After you discover how he has turned on you, you might call him:

- a ***false friend*** [*not to be confused with the linguistic term of the same name*]:
  not faithful or loyal :  treacherous *<a false friend>* ([m-w.com "false", def. 4a](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/false))
- a ***traitor***:
  one who betrays another's trust or is false to an obligation or duty  ([m-w.com def 1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/traitor))
- a ***backstabber***:
  [one who engages in] betrayal (as by a verbal attack against one not present) especially by a false friend ([m-w.com def. 1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backstabbing))
- a ***double-crosser***:
  to cheat or deceive (someone) especially by doing something that is different from what you said you would do ([m-w.com def. 1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double-cross))
- a ***two-timer***:
  1:  a double-crosser
  2:  one who betrays (a spouse or lover) by secret lovemaking with another ([m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/two-timer))
- ***disloyal***:
  failing to support or be true to someone or something : not loyal or faithful to your friends, family, country, etc.  ([m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disloyal))
- ***perfidious***:
  not able to be trusted : showing that someone cannot be trusted : characterized by perfidy (*the act of betraying someone or something : the state of not being loyal*) ([m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perfidious))

Comment: Your last selection is most excellent, sir!

Comment: Good selection, but in my experience (might be a UK thing) "two-timer" is more associated with somebody in a relationship who is having an affair. I've never heard it used except for "two-timing" (cheating) in a relationship.

Comment: What about *enemy agent*, *secret agent*, *double agent*, *turncoat*, *defector* and *mole* - all subtle differences depending on how and when the 'enemy' nature is revealed.

Comment: @Jasmine, those are all good words, but they fall under the *spy* category that the OP explicitly rejected, presumably because of the connotation of working for an opposing organization.

Comment: I am assuming the friend suggested spy because that's the genre we're in. I made it into an answer.

Comment: All of those suggest the person is actually your friend. A spy (I know, he's not a spy) isn't disloyal to the person (s)he is spying on.

Comment: You should cite a dictionary definition of these words, explain why you think they fit the given context, and what the differences are between them.

Answer (score 34):

There are lots of possible answers here.

This is quite a common social dynamic, so a lot of words have been discovered to be relevant.

*Frenemy* is a portmanteau that exactly describes this situation.

> **[frenemy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frenemy)** *noun* -  one who pretends to be a friend but is actually an enemy [*Merriam-Webster*]

Personally though, I think this a rather cringey word, I'd much sooner use some of the other suggestions.

Comment: _Frenemy_ being significantly different from the similarly derived and almost identical (in speech, anyway) _friendemy_, which is a friend that you're always arguing with and falling out with.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I’ve never understood why such ugly portmanteaux as those needed coining given that *an unfriend* has always been available in English.

Comment: @tchrist I would challenge the notion that any word has 'always been available', but I can't even find this one's etymology.  The [only results I can find](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unfriend) deal with social networking.

Comment: @SeanAllred OED: “unfriend, sb. (and a.) Etymology: ME. unfreond, -frend, = WFris. on-, ûnfrjeon, MDutch onvrient (Dutch -vriend), MLG. unvrund, MHG. unvriunt (G. unfreund). 1. One who is not a friend or on friendly terms; an enemy. In early use chiefly Sc. (sometimes in predicate without article), and in the 19th cent. app. revived by Scott. § ~1275 Lay. 5632 ― We sollen··slean houre onfrendes and wenden after Brenne. § ~1275 Lay. 17612 ― Wend to oure onfreondes and drif heom of londe. 
§ 1425 Wyntoun Cron. viii. xxvi. 3890 ― For he doutit þe gret mycht Off his vnfreyndis, and þare slycht.”&c

Comment: @SeanAllred Your challenge fails: the noun *unfriend* has been around **for over seven centuries** as the OED proves with its Middle English citations. See also my comments to the OP that illustrate 19th and 20th century uses that pathetically antedate “social networking” sillinesseses.  There are other citations between those, too.

Comment: @tchrist An unfriend is not nearly the same as a friendemy or a frenemy, though—it's closer to just plain _enemy_.

Comment: Why would anyone ever use "unfriend"? It sounds like something straight out of [Newspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak). (Not that I have some deep hatred of newspeak: there are some newspeak phrases that lend themselves to comedic and ironic usage, but not all of them :) )

Comment: I've seen "frenemy" used more to convey people who are enemies but are comfortable enough with their relationship that they seem to exhibit some characteristics of friendship.

Comment: What would a "frenemy with benefits" be? People who sleep together for the purpose of passing on STDs?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I’d say an ***unfriend*** {c,w,sh}ould be someone you weren’t on “friendly” terms with, one whom you considered “unfriendly”. That’s not (quite) the same as an *enemy*, whom I think of as someone whose will is specifically bent (up)on your downfall. Yet if you chase down *inimical*, you find definitions like the OED’s “Having the disposition or temper of an **enemy; unfriendly, hostile”** —which puts those all on pretty much the same footing. Still, there is no element of deception with *unfriend*, so it isn’t a suitable answer to the OP, appealing though it may otherwise be.

Comment: Please refer to the 1997 classic Arsonists - Frienemies from the album [As The World Burns](http://www.discogs.com/Arsonists-As-The-World-Burns/release/256273): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byWG9HVwOQk

Answer (score 22):

There’s also *[a wolf in sheep’s clothing](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20a%20wolf%20in%20sheep%27s%20clothing)*, which is a person who seems friendly but in truth is hostile.

Answer (score 21):

From your description, your friend is *two-faced* (*duplicitous*).  He may also be more generally *hypocritical*.

Comment: I think that *duplicitous* is a really good word for this, albeit with some qualification.

Answer (score 14):

If the cultural reference is appropriate to you and your audience, he's a [Judas](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/judas) (after Judas Isciarot, who betrayed Jesus to the Romans).

Comment: I don't know if this is coincidence or not, but I've only ever seen this in cases where money or a reward was involved.

Comment: @corsiKa That might be cultural. Where I'm from "Judas" is mostly used in the general sense, without the Biblical connotation "betrayal because of money/reward". (Most people around here are not that religious anymore.)

Answer (score 7):

The general answer is *traitor* or *backstabber*, but other answers are also possible, depending on factors such as the order of when they become your friend or enemy and the severity of the treachery.

If they were an enemy from the very beginning but approached you as a friend, working for someone else all along, they’d be a *spy*.

If they did not see you as an enemy but merely saw you as an asset, they’d be a *two-timer*.

But if all else fails, you can always resort to the good old *d’bag* or *a’hole*.

Answer (score 4):

*Double-dealing* - the practice of working to people's disadvantage behind their backs

Used as an adjective: "he is a backstabbing, double-dealing twister"

Answer (score 3):

In the US, he might be called a [Benedict Arnold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict_Arnold).

Answer (score 3):

While not necessarily an enemy or even a bad person, a *sociopath* can fit the bill when it comes to manipulation, lying, and lacking moral fiber.

If betrayal is the most important point to get across, then *turncoat* comes to mind, though it doesn't imply premeditation. *Viper* is often used to describe someone who hides their intentions and lies in wait until the ideal moment to strike.

Check out the answers to this question: [Metaphors similar to "Trojan Horse"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/187845/78544), many of them seem to fit your requirements.

Comment: Sociopath is definitely the word that comes to mind when someone is good at manipulating people when really they have malicious intentions.

Answer (score 2):

Or, if you want to get Shakespearian, you could call him *an Iago* (although that might be bit obscure for some).

In the play *Othello*, Iago is Othello’s trusted advisor, who is plotting to see Othello destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

**Brutus**
Someone who is a Brutus is a very good friend who gives you the screw job.
This is derived from Julius Caesar's best friend. His best friend Brutus was the last person to stab the dictator Julius Caesar's last words were "Et Tu, Brute?" which means "You too Brutus?"

Source [website](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=brutus)

Answer (score 1):

**Machiavellian**

While [Niccolò Machiavelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niccol%C3%B2_Machiavelli) has got some bad press, his name is used to describe a person who is

- Cunning, scheming, and unscrupulous ... [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Machiavellian)
- ... characterized by expediency, deceit, and cunning. [Yahoo](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/Machiavellian)
- ... cunning, amoral, and opportunist ... [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/machiavellian)

Such a person is nobody's friend. At best they treat you as a means to an end, or an ally of convenience.

Answer (score 1):

For a spy story, these are the words that came to my mind

*enemy agent* - typically you would use this for a known enemy.

*secret agent* - secret agents you just don't know about - who they work for is a secret.

*double agent* - this one is usually used when the agent is spying for both sides at the same time. It's most typically applied when someone has been "turned" away from the side they originally worked, and is now secretly working for the other side, while pretending everything is still normal and they are still working for you. This is a very common term in spy stories and will be easily understood by readers

*turncoat* - typically used for someone who visibly switches sides.

*defector* - typically used for someone who *officially* changes sides, declaring their intent in some official manner such as gaining citizenship in the enemy country.

*mole* - someone working inside your agency, pretending to work for you, but secretly working for the other side. Same as a double agent, but "mole" is used for more drama - there's an insidious factor about a mole, that doesn't exist with a double agent. This would be a good one - it's used a ton on American TV and I've seen it used in the British series "MI-6" as well. This one is so well known, there was a whole game show called ["The Mole"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mole_(U.S._TV_series)) where a group of people had to figure out who was secretly working against them.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're thinking of a

### Snake in the grass

> One who feigns friendship with the intent to deceive.

from [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/snake+in+the+grass)

Answer (score 0):

The word *mouth-friend* is one possible answer.

Comment: Try adding a source for this (dictionary) and an example usage.

Comment: @dwjohnston The source is the dictionary considered to be the first of its kind, Dr. Johnson's "A Dictionary of the English Language".

Answer (score 0):

Here are some adjectives you may find useful:

- Deceitful; guilty of or involving deceit; deceiving or misleading others.
- Mendacious; not telling the truth; lying.
- Perfidious; deceitful and untrustworthy.
- Sly; having or showing a cunning and deceitful nature.
- Surreptitious; kept secret, especially because it would not be approved of.
- Treacherous; guilty of or involving betrayal or deception.
- Duplicitous; deceitful.
- Underhand; acting or done in a secret or dishonest way.
- Unscrupulous; having or showing no moral principles; not honest or fair.

I understand some of these are synonyms, but you may find one you especially like.

Comment: None of these words mean "A person who pretends to be your friend, but is really your enemy".   They could _apply_ to such a person, but they don't _mean_ that....

Answer (score 0):

[Con artist or Confidence man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_trick) / [Link #2](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/con+artist)

Term is used in [social engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_(security)) for person who excel in psychological manipulation. In general, modus operandi is - pretending to be friendly while having malicious goal(s)*
Probably, the the most well known con artits is [Kevin Mitnick](https://twitter.com/kevinmitnick)

*just to be clear, it doesn't mean con artist is a "bad" person by default, e.g., security consultants