# Word or phrase for help that is really not helpful

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word, phrase or idiom that describes someone who is trying to help but actually hindering?  I find this a lot in a work context but sure it's common elsewhere.  I even think there may be a term for this in improv comedy.  Another possible application is those people who add comments that start with "I don't know but...."

Comment: Some consider 'If you can't help, don't hinder' to be idiomatic, but it's probably a lot less used than it used to be.

Comment: "Lead, follow, or get out of the way" -Thomas Paine

Comment: There's a popular idiom for this in many north, middle, and eastern European languages, "a bear's service". It was popularized through Jean La Fontaine's fable *L’ours et l’amateur des jardin* in the 17th century, though the idea itself is likely older and the ultimate origin remains unknown. At any rate, for whatever reason the idiom never reached England's shores. Alas.

Comment: "Like a comment on Stack Exchange"

Comment: "He offers all assistance apart from actual help."

Comment: possible duplicate  of               https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188604/what-is-a-word-that-means-someone-who-pretends-to-be-your-friend-but-is-actuall/188618#188618

Comment: I've seen "hlep" used to describe unhelpful help... Like when autocorrect tries to change "hlep" into "help."

Answer (score 1):

That person can be considered 'well meaning' which describe a person who tries to help but tends to just get in the way.

> Bob means well, but just keeps getting in the way.

A stronger version of this is 'well intentioned' which would describe a person who tries to help but tends to make things worse.

#### References

- [Cambridge Dictionary - well meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/well-meaning)
- [Cambridge Dictionary - well intentioned](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/well-intentioned)

Answer (score 0):

You can say,

> **"You're causing more harm than help."**

or

> **"Your help is [counterproductive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counterproductive)."**

The first one is quite common than the later.

*Hope, this helped :)*

Answer (score 0):

If you're leaning more towards the comedic effect, there are some off-beat similes that I've heard.

> A woman needs a man *like a fish needs a bicycle*.

It seems like a bicycle would be useful, but clearly not for a fish.

> My sister is a graceful *as a bull in a china shop*.
>
> She's *like a porcupine in a balloon factory*.

These similes emphasize the counterproductive (or perhaps destructive) nature of one's actions.

Answer (score 0):

[lexico] disservice: a harmful action   You can use the phrase "do somebody a disservice".                Slater actually does viewers a disservice by being less than embarrassing here.

But I would be doing the author a great disservice if I gave any impression that this is a political tract.                                                  The article does a real disservice to those children who do have learning differences.

Answer (score -1):

I think the idiom can answer the OP's query.

> He is  a wolf in sheep's skin or clothing.

He seems to be  friendly  but  he  is harmful

see the link.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-wolf-in-sheep-s-clothing

Comment: A wolf trying to help (see the actual question)?